# What is the portfolio repository trying to say?

Tags: creative-commons

I am using some code from Material Design Lite's example portfolio. The html and css is under a Creative Commons Attribution International 4.0 License, but the repository states:

> As an exception to this license, all html or css that is generated by
> the software at the direction of the user is copyright the user. The
> user has full ownership and control over such content, including
> whether and how they wish to license it.

I'm not really sure what the above blockquote means.

Comment: Could you link to the document from which the quote is taken?

Comment: Sure, it comes from https://getmdl.io/templates/, download the portfolio one

Answer (score 2):

It says what it says. The tool's output is not covered by the license of the tool. Same as the output of a video editor is not covered by the license of the tool. Or a compiled program is not covered by the licence of the compiler.

This exception is needed, as the tool (probably) injects a lot of its own code into the output. This will make the output a derivative work. The exception allows you to use the tool without this restriction.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get what software they are referring to. When I download the zip, there is nothing to generate; the html and css are already there. I don't see any pug or sass that would imply generation

Comment: I can't see it ether, but that is because I don't have a link to it. You can help we with this.

Comment: Sure, here: https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/mdl-template-portfolio.zip